# JS - compare select option then make it selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

We have several `<select>` fields that need to be set at the specified `<option>`. We have this "answer list" with UUID. Every `<option>` is evaluated: if the UUID is included at "answer list" then thats the `<option>` selected, otherwise we keep default "not available" `<option>` selected.

See below my current code, the comparison is the part I'm facing trouble.

JS code:

```
$('#severalStores .selectLimitInformation').each(function () { //Scan all the select fields        
    $(this).find("option").each(function () { //Search within every option            
        $.each(JSON.parse(answerList), function (item) { //Scan all "answer list"

            //Compare values then choose value (not working)
            if ($(this).option.value == item.expectedUUID)
                $(this).val(item.expectedUUID);
            else
                $(this).val('0');
            $(this).trigger('change');
        });
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="row form-horizontal" id="severalStores">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Store AAA:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select class="form-control selectLimitInformation">
                    @foreach (...) //data from ViewBag
                    {
                        <option value="@storeLimit.info">@storeLimit.description</option>
                    }
                    <option value="0">Not available</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Store BBB:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select class="form-control selectLimitInformation">
                    @foreach (...) //data from ViewBag
                    {
                        <option value="@storeLimit.info">@storeLimit.description</option>
                    }
                    <option value="0">Not available</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        //Several other select
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the problem is?

Comment: With that script browser returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')" at "$(this).option.value" point. It seems to me that it expects "option[n]" but I couldn't make it work

Comment: Inside `$.each()`, `this` is the current element of `answerList` (the same as `item`), not the `<select>` from the outer loop.

Comment: You're changing the value of the select for each element in `answerList`. So the final value will just be based on the last element of `answerList`. Can you show a sample of `answerList` and what the desired result should be?

Comment: Also, the arguments to the `$.each()` callback function are `index, element`. So `item` is not the array element, it's the index.

Comment: @Barmar the ```answerList``` contains several UUID codes. Those ```select``` were made with a larger set of UUID, therefore each ```option``` is a UUID value. The goal is to find if any ```option``` matches the UUID at the ```answerList```, and if so, make it the selected one.

Comment: What if multiple options are in answerList?

Comment: So you just want `if (answerList.includes(option.value))`

Comment: @Barmar I've updated my post, changed ```expectedUUID``` with ```answerList``` at ```if```, as you mentioned previously

Comment: **Please** add a sample of the `answerList` array.

Comment: `let expectedValues = answerList.map(item => item.expectedUUID)`. Then you can use `if (expectedValues.includes(option.value))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247826/discussion-between-rd1218-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the nested loops. Put all the expected UUIDs in a `Set`. Then you can use the `.has()` method to test if the option value is in the set, and update the `select` value.

```js
answerList = JSON.parse(answerList);
let expectedUUIDs = new Set(answerList.map(a => a.expectedUUID));
$('#severalStores .selectLimitInformation').each(function(i, select) { //Scan all the select fields    
  select.value = "0"; // start with a default    
  $(this).find("option").each(function(j, option) { //Search within every option      
    if (expectedUUIDs.has(option.value)) {
      select.value = option.value;
      return false; // stop looping over the options
    }
  });
});
```